# Karel screen is blank when trying to run in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, karel

I'm currently doing the online CS106A Stanford course. As part of this I need to install Eclipse and get Karel running

I installed Eclipse using their up to date version of Eclipse, installed using instructions from here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/eclipse.shtml , I also installed Java using the same instructions.

I am trying to launch Karel and get it running 
However I get a blank screen as seen
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKzwr.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this? I am running Java 8 Update 121

Comment: I'm attempting to get it running using the following guide:

Answer (score 4):

For updated reference, Anonymous's answer also worked for me, at least for the initial Karel assignment, and I'm also using Java 1.8 downloaded from the current-day CS106A sites.

What worked for me: (a) renamed the karel.jar file that came with the SEE assignments to karel_old.jar, and then (b) copied in the jar of the Blank Karel Project at: https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a//resources/BlankKarelProject.zip

to the Assignment 1 project and renamed it to karel.jar (from the Finder - am on a Mac).  Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately, the link is outdated. The working one is https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106a/cs106a.1174/resources/BlankKarelProject.zip

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue **install an older version of Java**.

If you're on a mac Homebrew makes it easier to download and install different versions of java. Examples here: https://gist.github.com/gwpantazes/50810d5635fc2e053ad117b39b597a14

I was running into the same problem(blank screen) as the initial poster when trying to run Karel the robot with the newest version of Java. It ran correctly when I switched to java version 6.

**After installing a different java JDK set the compiler of your java IDE to use the correct version of java**

**Consider using a java version manager** to make it easier to switch versions. I'm on a mac so I used jenv – https://www.jenv.be/

There is a post on medium here for more info on using jenv that was helpful – https://medium.com/@brunofrascino/working-with-multiple-java-versions-in-macos-9a9c4f15615a

Answer (score 0):

I actually stumbled upon the issue, just recently. If you get the assignments from [Stanford SEE Website](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS106A), and installed the Eclipse from the [Current Stanford Class Website](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/), (like, in my situation, it was because I'm running on Windows 10 Pro, and I need the x64 Eclipse version as the one in [Stanford SEE Website](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS106A) is based on the old x32 Eclipse version) you have to get or download the assignments from [Current Stanford Class Website](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/) instead. Try to use those assignment files as your working assignment files or replace the karel.jar file in the [Stanford SEE Website](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS106A)'s assignment files with the karel.jar file from [Current Stanford Class Website](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs106a/)'s assignment files. In my case, it worked like charmed.

My JDK/JRE running version info: 1.8.

*PS: Sorry with the redundant wording of the "*assignment files*".

Answer (score 0):

2019 standford assignment folder has file name called spl.jar.

In order to run old file, replace karel.jar with spl.jar and rename spl.jar to karel.jar, it should work.